# how to bind an AutoComplete Textbox with DB by JQuery and Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I want to bind a textbox with a field of DB by using JQuery Code, but I     don't know what parameter I can use in AutoComplete function

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var availableTags = [??????];
        $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags });
  });
```

**behind code**

```
public partial class MasterProfile : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
      SqlConnection cnn = new  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbpath"]);

 protected void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   FindFriends();
}

void FindFriends()
{
    SqlDataReader dr;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cnn;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * From tblUser where UInfo Like @P1 and UID<> @P2 Order by UInfo";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", "%" + txtSearch.Text + "%");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P2", Convert.ToInt64(Session["ud"]));
    cnn.Open();

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    txtSearch.Text = dr["UInfo"].ToString();
    txtSearch.DataBind();
    cnn.Close();
}
}
```

Comment: **[Here is the link](http://dotnetmentors.com/aspnet/jquery-autocomplete-by-example.aspx)** on how you can achieve it

Comment: Here is the simple (easy to understand) example of Simple autocomplete textbox using jquery http://www.dotnetspan.com/2014/08/jquery-autocomplete-example-using-aspnet.html

Comment: thanks for helping. I did all of you've said, but when I execute , only error part of JQuery runs. means this part---->  error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error");
can I do something more?